# How to change the cycle for drawing points on a sphere THREEjs?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, three.js, cycle

How to change the cycle for drawing points on a sphere THREEjs? Its very slow and i cant see my meshes.
my code below:

```
let R = 600;

let phi_rad = phi * Math.PI / 180;
let theta_rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;

for (var theta = 0; theta < 180; theta++) {

    for (var phi = 0; phi < 360; phi++) {
        let random_bm_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100);
        let random_bm_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        let random_bm_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(random_bm_geometry, random_bm_material);

        let x = R * Math.cos(theta_rad) * Math.cos(phi_rad);
        let y = R * Math.cos(theta_rad) * Math.sin(phi_rad);
        let z = R * Math.sin(theta_rad) * Math.sin(phi_rad);
        let sq = 1/Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

        random_bm_mesh.position.x = R*x*sq;
        random_bm_mesh.position.y = R*y*sq;
        random_bm_mesh.position.z = R*z*sq;
        scene.add(random_bm_mesh);
        random_bm_array.push(random_bm_mesh);


    };

};
```

What shoud i change, because 2 for cycles are weird.

Comment: Any error messages/warnings in browser's console?

Comment: nope, just 25s + for running 3js scene and hard animation of globe

Comment: Why do you want to use so many meshes instead of single `THREE.Points()`?

Comment: Just didn*t look at examples with Points. Thanks